# draw edges with networkx in python

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, networkx, graph-visualization

I have a graph with float coordinate position(ex: (1.3 , 2.75)) and draw my graph with nodes and some special edges. and G.edges is type of networkx.classes.reportviews.EdgeView, for example:

```
print(G.edges)
```

=>(((29.637096774193548, 61.74242424242425), (52.822580645161295, 35.76839826839827)),(...),...)
and my code is:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=G.edges())
```

that

> KeyError:(29.637096774193548, 61.74242424242425)

Answer (score 0):

it solved. the edges add with its keys in dictoinary (pos) and i add ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) to edges.
i change my code and add(0,1) to edges that 0 assign to (x1,y1) and 1 assign to (x2,y2) in nodelist or pos.